# How can I repeat an AnimationSet in java?

Tags: java, android

I am basically trying to get a text to vibrate; I created a few animations and put them in an AnimationSet but can't get it to repeat. I've looked through a bunch of solutions here and haven't gotten any to work for me yet. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or suggest a better way? My code is as following:

```
package com.example.dealbreaker;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationSet;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class LobbyOwner extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lobby_owner);
        ShakeIt();
    }

    private void ShakeIt() {
        final int animationTime = 1000;
        final int fromXDelta = 0;
        final int fromYDelta = 0;
        AnimationSet textAnimSet = new AnimationSet(true);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            final float randomX = (float) Math.random();
            final float randomY = (float) Math.random();
            float toXDelta = (randomX < 0.5) ? randomX * 10: -randomX * 10;
            float toYDelta = (randomY < 0.5) ? randomY * 10: -randomY * 10;
            TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(fromXDelta, toXDelta, fromYDelta, toYDelta);
            TranslateAnimation antiAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(fromXDelta, -toXDelta, fromYDelta, -toYDelta);
            animation.setStartOffset(i * animationTime);
            textAnimSet.addAnimation(animation);
            textAnimSet.addAnimation(antiAnimation);
        }
        Log.i("AnimationSet", textAnimSet.getAnimations().toString()); //shows 10 animations in the animationset
        textAnimSet.setDuration(animationTime);
        textAnimSet.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                //do I need something here?
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                //textAnimSet.start(); //doesn't work?!
                //tv.startAnimation(textAnimSet); //doesn't work
                //Log.i("Information", "We are here"); //generates 3 outputs???
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.excitedLobbyTxtView);
        tv.clearAnimation();
        tv.startAnimation(textAnimSet);
    }

}
```

Comment: The antiAnimation is used to get the text back to it's original position but this doesn't seem to run after the previous animation either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try to reset your animation when its finished for i `textAnimSet.reset();`
complet code :

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ShakeIt();
    }


    private void ShakeIt() {
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.excitedLobbyTxtView);
        tv.clearAnimation();


        final int animationTime = 1000;
        final int fromXDelta = 0;
        final int fromYDelta = 0;
        AnimationSet textAnimSet = new AnimationSet(true);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            final float randomX = (float) Math.random();
            final float randomY = (float) Math.random();
            float toXDelta = (randomX < 0.5) ? randomX * 10: -randomX * 10;
            float toYDelta = (randomY < 0.5) ? randomY * 10: -randomY * 10;
            TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(fromXDelta, toXDelta, fromYDelta, toYDelta);
            TranslateAnimation antiAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(fromXDelta, -toXDelta, fromYDelta, -toYDelta);
            animation.setStartOffset(i * animationTime);
            textAnimSet.addAnimation(animation);
            textAnimSet.addAnimation(antiAnimation);
        }
        Log.i("AnimationSet", textAnimSet.getAnimations().toString()); //shows 10 animations in the animationset
        textAnimSet.setDuration(animationTime);
        textAnimSet.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                //do I need something here?
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                textAnimSet.reset();
                textAnimSet.startNow();
                //textAnimSet.start(); //doesn't work?!
                //tv.startAnimation(textAnimSet); //doesn't work
                //Log.i("Information", "We are here"); //generates 3 outputs???
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });


      tv.startAnimation(textAnimSet);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I found another way where I could use tv.startAnimation(textAnimSet) if I moved the declaration of tv above the setAnimationListener, but this works as well!

Comment: Yep for first time i started the animation with a button and when i tested without button that's not working if you declare the listner above start animation

Answer (score 1):

I figured out why I couldn't restart the animation, I had declared my view tv *below* my AnimationListener and therefore I couldn't access the variable... I am still confused on why the animation won't return the same direction even with the antiAnimation-variable though.
The working code is as follows:

```
package com.example.dealbreaker;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationSet;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class LobbyOwner extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lobby_owner);
        ShakeIt();
    }

    private void ShakeIt() {
        final int animationTime = 20;
        final int fromXDelta = 0;
        final int fromYDelta = 0;
        AnimationSet textAnimSet = new AnimationSet(true);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            final float randomX = (float) Math.random();
            final float randomY = (float) Math.random();
            float toXDelta = (randomX < 0.5) ? randomX * 10: -randomX * 10;
            float toYDelta = (randomY < 0.5) ? randomY * 10: -randomY * 10;
            TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(fromXDelta, toXDelta, fromYDelta, toYDelta);
            TranslateAnimation antiAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(-toXDelta, fromXDelta, -toYDelta, fromYDelta);
            animation.setStartOffset(i * animationTime);
            textAnimSet.addAnimation(animation);
            textAnimSet.addAnimation(antiAnimation);
        }
        textAnimSet.setDuration(animationTime);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.excitedLobbyTxtView);
        tv.clearAnimation();
        textAnimSet.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                tv.startAnimation(textAnimSet);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
        tv.startAnimation(textAnimSet);
    }

}
```